# Can't retrieve ServerHandler by calling app.getElementById(id) function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a `FlexTable` with dynamic number of rows. Each row contains a `TextBox`. There is a button to add new row to the table. And a Submit button that should send all `TextBox` widgets for processing.

I have initially declared a `ServerHandler` and added to it all fixed elements:

```
var handler = app.createServerHandler('handler12')
    .addCallbackElement(fixedTextBox1)
    .addCallbackElement(fixedTextBox2);
handler.setId('myHandlerId');
button.addClickHandler(handler);
```

Note that I have set an **id** to the handler. Now when I process the addition of new `TextBox` (row to the table) I have to call `addCallbackElement(newlyCreatedField)` to the handler. Otherwise I will not have it as param when the form is submitted.

I do this:

```
var handler = app.getElementById('myHandlerId');
handler.addCallbackElement(newlyCreatedField);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error encountered: Cannot find function addCallbackElement in object Generic.
```

I logged the type of the `handler` var with `Logger.log(handler.getType())` and it says `Generic`. I called `app.getElementById(id)` on non-existent id and it again returns an object of type `Generic`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for looking into this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Srik beat me to it...) You don't need to have every TextBox as a CallbackElement, if you have the container as a CallbackElement.

You will need to keep the names of the contained TextBox elements unique, and keep track of those names. To do that, you can use a Tag, and update it as you go.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  // FlexTable - use tag to count # rows.
  var fTable = app.createFlexTable()
                  .setId('fTable')
                  .setTag('0');
  app.add(fTable);

  // Button to add new row
  var addRow = app.createButton('Add Row');
  app.add(addRow);
  var addRowHandler = app.createServerHandler('addRowHandler');
  addRowHandler.addCallbackElement(fTable);
  addRow.addClickHandler(addRowHandler);

  // Submit button
  var submit = app.createButton('Submit');
  app.add(submit);
  var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler('submitHandler');
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(fTable);
  submit.addClickHandler(submitHandler);

  return app;
}

function addRowHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var row = parseInt( e.parameter.fTable_tag );  // Get row counter
  var tBox = 'textBox'+row;

  var textBox = app.createTextBox()
                   .setId(tBox)
                   .setName(tBox);

  // Place new text box in FlexTable
  var fTable = app.getElementById('fTable');
  fTable.setWidget(row, 0, textBox);

  // Update row counter
  fTable.setTag((++row).toString());

  return app;
}

function submitHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var rows = parseInt( e.parameter.fTable_tag );  // Get row counter

  // Log contents of all textBoxes in FlexTable
  for (var row=0; row<rows; row++) {
    var tBox = 'textBox'+row;
    Logger.log(tBox+'='+e.parameter[tBox]);
  }

  return app;
}
```

A more complete example of using dynamic form elements is available on Waqar's [Apps Script Tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/miscellaneous/creating-form-elements-dynamically-using-google-apps-script-gas).

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason why you want to add each text box as a callback element. If not I suggest that you add the Flextable as the callback element and all the elements within the Flextable will be recognized in your handler functions.

```
var handler = app.createServerHandler('handler12')
    .addCallbackElement(flexTable);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I never new I could add the whole table as a callback element.